# Update google spreadsheet using python client API on GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, gdata

I've got a google spreadsheet owned by a GAE service account and I want my GAE Python app to update a cell in one of the rows.

Based on some reading, these are my findings:

- the spreadsheets service is old-school. It's a Google Data API and most Google services are now on the Google API platform. For Google API services, one can use a service account to do two-legged oauth2 access, but not for Google Data API services. Oh, it seems one can do two-legged oauth on Google Data API services, but only if the app is on a Google Apps domain (which mine isn't)
- I could implement a similar effect (i.e. a user of the app can use data in my spreadsheet and doesn't need to login or authorize in any way) by using my personal account. There's a complicated way that involves me to authorize the app once, store the token and reuse it when a user uses the app. There's another way, which is to use client login (i.e. I embed my personal login and password in the code and use it to authorize the app to access the data in my spreadsheet)

This latter approach seems fairly safe as well, but of course I must be very careful that my source code will not be exposed. The authorization is between the GAE app and the Google Data Spreadsheets API, so the actual user's machine is not involved at all.

My spreadsheet is owned by the service account and shared with my personal account.

Note that my app is also using the Google Drive API (to access some personal Drive files, also shared between me and the GAE service account), so for that it will authorize using the service account.

Can someone confirm that my findings are correct and this approach is sound?

Comment: Oh, and just to add a comment in the sideline: when using the Google Data spreadsheets API Python client library, it was very confusing to find two packages, one called 'gdata.spreadsheet' and one called 'gdata.spreadsheets'. Only after a lot of trial and error, it appeared that the first is an older version. One should use the latter to have full oauth2 support. Not that it really matters in this case, since (I believe) I'm stuck with client login...

Comment: Just popped to my mind that a major drawback to the client login approach is that my app must be updated whenever I change my personal Google password... Any ideas when the spreadsheets service will be introduced on Google API platform ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdata.spreadsheets.client (Google Data API) on the OAuth2 (Google API platform) flow.

https://github.com/HatsuneMiku/googleDriveAccess

It uses 'oauth2client-gdata-bridge'.